# Send Slack Notifications with a flow in Salesforce doesn't Work

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow, slack, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

We're currently facing an issue while trying to set up a flow in Salesforce to send messages to Slack when specific fields are updated in an opportunity.

Here's what we've done so far:

- Connected Salesforce with Sales Cloud for Slack app.
- Assigned the "Sales Cloud for Slack" permission set.
- Invited the Sales Bot to the desired Slack channel.
- Created a flow in Salesforce to trigger Slack notifications when certain opportunity fields are updated.
  [image]

We successfully tested the connection with the debug function with a test opportunity in our flow. The Sales Bot app was able to send notifications to the right channel. However, when we activate the flow and change the fields in the same test opportunity, we can not receive any Slack notifications.
[image]

We've checked our configurations and can't seem to identify where the problem lies. Could there be any potential issues we might have overlooked? Any insights or guidance on troubleshooting this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when activated, what does the debug log look like? Is the flow's entry condition met? Does the RFI decision get the correct outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Flow Trigger:

- Trigger Type: Double-check that your flow is a record-triggered flow with Opportunity as the object and triggered "After Trigger." Avoid using "Before Trigger" as it might not capture updates if other validation rules trigger.
- Criteria: Ensure your trigger has no criteria that might be unintentionally filtering out the desired updates. Keep it simple at first and test with all updates.
- Schedule: Verify the flow is not scheduled, as this can override the record-triggered behavior.

Field Update:

- Field Accessibility: Are the updated fields accessible to the user running the flow? User profiles and permission sets can restrict field access.
- Data Type Mismatch: Check if the data type of the updated field in your flow matches the actual field data type. Mismatches can cause errors even if debug shows success.

Flow Elements:

- Slack Action Configuration: Is the selected channel correct in the "Post Message" action? Is the bot user invited and active in that channel?
- Variable Mapping: Confirm that the field values are correctly mapped to the corresponding variables in the "Post Message" action. Use data transformations if needed.
- Flow Errors: Check the flow's "Run History" for any errors or warnings. They might provide clues about what's failing.

Comment: Looks a bit like AI helped, doesn't it?!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I just checked: 1. It is a record triggered flow with the After save trigger. 2. trigger criteria will not unintentionally filter out the desired updates, just the dates are not blank and is changed 3. the flow is not scheduled. 4. The fields are accessible to the user running the flow, because we used the admin user and with all permissions. 5.data types match, there are only dates. 6. the channel ID is correct 7. Sales bot is in the channel and active.